# Problem with table in itemize

Tags: tables, tabularx, itemize

So i have following code snippet

[image]

if i run it i get following output

[image]

But i would like to have the table inside the itemize column not the section column.

What can i do ? Thanks for any help

Comment: Please don't post images of code snippets. Always add a minimal but working example to your question. However: Don't use a `table` environment if you only want a `tabular`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `tabular` (or `tabularx`) it will fit in the indented list boundaries. If you use a `table` environment (even with `[H]`) then that specifies that the table is *not* part of the text flow so it is always set in a normalised setting not using the current line width or fonts etc.

So just use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
```

note `\linewidth` is the current width of (indented) lines within a list,
and remove the `\begin{table}`  and `\end{table}`.